# I have 5x5 matrix , need to replace repeated numbers to zero

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a 5x5 matrix, and I need to replace repeated numbers to zero.
I'm trying to create 5x5 matrix with multidimensions arrays, and one-dimension array to compare values. But it displayed unexpectedly.
What am I doing wrong?

```
using System;
 namespace labr6 {
   class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int[,] mas = new int[5, 5];

        int[] val = new int[10];

        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    mas[i, j] = r.Next(1, 100);
                    val[c] = r.Next(1, 100);
                    
                    foreach (int x in mas)
                    {
                        if (x == val[c])
                        {
                            mas[i, j] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    Console.Write(mas[i, j] + " ");
                    
                }
                
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            
        }
    }
} }
```

Comment: I am not following what you are trying to “compare.” You state that… _”I have 5x5 matrix, and i need to replace repeated numbers to zero.”_ … ? … What repeated numbers? And numbers only in the 5x5 array? It appears the code is filling two (2) arrays with random numbers… one is a 5x5 array, the other is a 10x1. The code “appears” to be comparing the numbers in both arrays in an odd way. Again I am not getting what you are comparing. Can you elaborate?

Comment: *At a first look,* the result of `r.Next(1, 100)` changes every time you call it. What you need to do is `int randNum = r.Next(1, 100); mas[i, j] = randNum; val[c] = randNum;`.

Comment: Would you give some sample that explains what you are trying to do? Why you have 3 nested loops in the first place is not understandable.

Comment: I have to arrays , one of them is 2D , another is 1D , im trying to compare this arrays and replace repeated number to zero.

Comment: @AndrewMorton thanks I'll try it

Comment: The inner `foreach` loop looks quite odd. It is looping through the 5x5 `mas` array where `x` represents the current element in `mas`. Then… `if (x == val[c])` … the code sets … `mas[i, j] = 0;` … ? … How do you know that `x` is the [I,j] element in `mas`? This cannot be right.

Comment: Just checking: are you trying to generate random numbers from 1 to 99 or from 1 to 100?

Comment: It appears that you are only checking if 10 numbers out of a possible 99 in a 5x5 matrix (i.e. 25) are repeated. I don't understand the purpose.

Comment: Is it possible that you simply want to ensure that your 5x5 grid contains no duplicated numbers? If so, that's very easy.

Comment: @Enigmativity yes, something like that, and make duplicated numbers equal to zero

Comment: @KuroIsekai - No, I'm asking if you want to create it in the first place with no duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By brute force, you can compare each item of the matrix. But, there is a more efficient way, you can use a hash table to perform the comparative it would run in O(n*m) where n and m are the size of the matrix, something like this:

```
       int[,] arr = new int[5, 5] {
          {1, 2, 6, 2, 1 }, 
          {4, 1, 5, 3, 4 }, 
          {6, 1, 8, 9, 8 },
          {6, 2, 4, 1, 0 },
          {3, 1, 8, 7, 9 },
       };
    
       HashSet<int> unique = new HashSet<int>();
    
       for(int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
       {
           for(int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
           {
               if (arr[i,j] != 0 && !unique.Add(arr[i,j]))
                {
                    arr[i,j] = 0;  // Not unique, replace with 0
                }
           }
       }
       
       // Print the arr
       for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++) {
                Console.Write("{0} ", arr[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

You can see, the implementation details here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UZZjNk

If you need to perform the comparative against a 1D array, you can modify the snippet code above and add first the 1D array to the hash table.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I need to do it with “foreach”.

Comment: It could be done by replacing both cycles with `foreach` and filling a new matrix with each element or zero depending it is repeated or not.